# Script tag with type="text/html" and src="..." loaded, but ignored by jQuery

Tags: jquery, firefox, header, firebug, jquery-templates

My page has a tag:

```
    <script id='header' src='/Templates/Shared/Header.tmpl.html' type='text/html'></script>
```

Firebug tells me that Firefox 5 is requesting this resource. On the HTML tab, I can navigate to the script element and see that it contains the contents of /Template/Shared/Header.tmpl.html.

jQuery, however, insists that the script tag is empty. $('#header').html() returns an empty string. I don't understand why.

Yes, I can load the file with $.get() and use $('#header').html(data) to set the contents. Then I can use it as I would expect. This obviously generates a second request, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: I wonder if this is jQuery being strict. Have you tried using .text() instead of .html()? I am not certain that it will work, because I don't know that the script tag is actually part of the DOM. I think the metadata plugin can access information inside of script tags, but I have not used it personally. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata

Comment: .text() or .html() makes no difference in this case, but your idea about not being in the DOM seems valid. None of the external scripts have content. I'm looking in to the metadata plugin now. Thanks!

Comment: Found a similar question, with no good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148441/how-can-i-get-the-content-of-the-file-specified-as-the-src-of-a-script-tag

Comment: Not sure why the original post includes an HTML page as a script.  The script tag normally has a link to a Javascript file in the src attribute and a type "text/javascript" or no type attribute at all.

Comment: "This obviously generates a second request, which I would like to avoid" the src of the element also generates a request, so I don't see where is the extra request... just saying

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but the answer is simple. The script tag simply does not contain any text or html.

`<script id='...' src='...' type='...'></script>`

There are no elements or text within the tag. The script will be requested and loaded into memory (if the script type has a handler), but the actual text itself will not be inserted into the DOM.

Comment: is there then a property of the dom element that you can access where the result of the request is stored? something like `document.getElementById("myHtmlScript").contents`?

Comment: It's been a while since I've studied the DOM apis in depth. What are you trying to accomplish? Traditionally speaking, if you want to load some other uri's asset as text in to a variable you would use ajax or jsonp (which is basically just loading a script that then executes and adds text to the document). Are you trying to accomplish something in particular?

Comment: it just makes perfect sense that if **A**is true and **B** is true that **A+B** would also be true, **A** being the fact that `<script>` can have either inline content *or* src attribute and *B* being the fact that a `<script>` tag can be either `type="application/javascript"` or `type="text/html"` among other options.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old problem, but still existing in Firefox. I use a workaround for it:

```
function getHtml(selector) {
  var $element = $(selector);
  var html = $element.html();

  if (!html ) {
    // copy all the children elements to a dummy DIV, which, unlike the SCRIPT have no problem providing the html in Firefox
    html= $('<div />').append($element.children().clone()).html();
  }
  return html;
}
```