# How can I add a script as code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the content of the file specified as the ‘src’ of a <script> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148441/how-can-i-get-the-content-of-the-file-specified-as-the-src-of-a-script-tag)

I want to print my "definition" of script, preventing it will be executed.

Tried with :

```
var scriptWidget = document.createElement('script');
scriptWidget.type = 'text/javascript';
scriptWidget.src = "http://www.mywebsite.it/file.js";

$('#widget-html-codici').html(escape(scriptWidget));
```

but it prints `%5Bobject%20HTMLScriptElement%5D`.
How can I print the code as "code"?

Comment: It is not printed as text...always as script but with another type...

Comment: do you want to print the source code of the `file.js` or print the actual script tag `<script ...></script`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you simply use the following:

```
var script = '<script type="text/javascript" '    // pay attention to
    + 'src="http://www.mywebsite.it/file.js"></'  // splitting of '</'
    + 'script>';                                  // and 'script>'

$('#widget-html-codici').text(script);​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/NPBJm/

Comment: uhm..that's nice! Never use .text() before :) Thank you!

Comment: Alternatively, escape the `<` and `>` characters with `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively. (Also, `&apos;` for `'`)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
var scriptWidget = document.createElement('script');
scriptWidget.type = 'text/javascript';
scriptWidget.src = "http://www.mywebsite.it/file.js";

console.log(scriptWidget.outerHTML);
```

[**Demo on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qebCy/)

Comment: `alert` and `console.log` is not the same as pushing the value to the markup: http://jsfiddle.net/qebCy/1/.