# How to get content of <script src="..."> when html runs from local file system?

Tags: javascript, html

There is [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148441/how-can-i-get-the-content-of-the-file-specified-as-the-src-of-a-script-tag) asking how to get content of `<script src="...">`. The answer is to use ajax for that. However, this will not work when the html file is not hosted on web server. Is there another option that work for html files accessed both from web server and from local file system?

Comment: No. For obvious security reasons.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol What are these obvious reasons?

Comment: @sahbeewah If JavaScript could read any given file on your filesystem, then I could just download your entire hard drive with a single malicious link.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @user2182349 I am generating another self-contained html file (without any dependencies) and therefore I need to access content of some runtime scripts to inline them in the resulting html.

Comment: Generate your HTML file with a build tool like Grunt and inline the scripts that way.

Comment: @pherris All users will then have to install node.js. I need to do it in plain HTML opened in browser.

Answer (score 0):

To read the file:

```
<base href="file:///C:/path/to/your/folder/"/>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.id = 'iframe';
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.src = 'myJs.js';
    setTimeout(function(){
        var text = document.getElementById('iframe').contentDocument.body.firstChild.innerHTML;
        alert(text);
    }, 1000);
}
</script>
```

or you can

```
<script>
function readfile() {
    alert(document.getElementById('iframe').contentDocument.body.firstChild.innerHTML);
}
</script>
<iframe id='iframe' src = 'test.txt' onload='readfile()'> </iframe>
```

attach an onload event to the iframe calling a function reading the contents of the text-file an doing whatever as soon as possible.

Comment: Error: "Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame." (Google Chrome 45)