# How do I access the innerHTML / text / contents of a remote script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to get the html / inner content / text of all the script tags that are loaded on the page. Here is some sample code:

```
<script name="test1">
    alert('hi');
</script>
<script src="https://example.com/js.js name="test2""></script>
```

When I include jQuery, and run the following, I can't seem to get access the content of the remote script:

`alert( jQuery('script[name="test2"]').html() )`

Any thoughts on why that is?

Comment: because there is no content inside of the tag. The browser does not inject it into the page, it is evaluated.

Comment: i think you can get whole inner content of script by using ajax try to request with that src and get response of content of that script

Comment: The syntax on the second `script` tag is broken. You've put the quotes in the wrong place

Comment: Answers are horrible with this, but it is a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148441/how-can-i-get-the-content-of-the-file-specified-as-the-src-of-a-script-tag

Comment: scripts don't have HTML inside them, by definition. And yes, ones which link to an external source definitely don't, the code is just fetched and evaluated, it doesn't become part of the DOM. But why do you want to, anyway?

Comment: Ahh okay yes I just saw that question. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the content of the file specified as the 'src' of a <script> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148441/how-can-i-get-the-content-of-the-file-specified-as-the-src-of-a-script-tag)